# Applying retryWhen to a custom observer that throws an error, not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rxjs, reactivex

I'm using this custom `class` to connect to MongoDB in a reactivex way:

```
function RxMongodb(driver){
    driver == null ? this.driver = require('mongodb').MongoClient : this.driver = driver.MongoClient;
}

RxMongodb.prototype.connect = function(uri){
    return Rx.Observable.create((observer)=>{
        if (dbInstance != null){
            console.log('already connected, repassing db instance');
            observer.next(dbInstance);
        } else {
            console.log('connecting for the first time');
            this.driver.connect(uri, (err, db)=>{
                if (err) {
                    console.log('rx mongo error! ' + err);
                    observer.error(err);
                } else {
                    dbInstance = db;
                    observer.next(dbInstance);
                    observer.complete();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Sometimes my mongodb takes time to load (it's called together with this code), so I want to wait and try again. I'm using `retryWhen` to do this:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(emitter, 'go').
flatMap(()=>rx_mongo.connect(mongo_parameters.url)).                   
retryWhen(errors=>errors.delay(2000)).take(10).
...
```

Here `rx_mongo` is an instance of `RxMongbdb`. I can see in the console that an error occurred, so it called `observer.error(err)`, but it won't ever retry anything.

Also, I see a lot of documentation that uses onNext, onError, onCompleted instead of next, error, completed. Which one is the modern? It's mine, right?

**UPDATE**:

I think it might have to do with error(). What's the difference of calling error() and throwing an error?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the **retryWhen** in the wrong place... you have to put it on the mongo connect observable. Although, the mongo connect Observable must be hot and not fired every time the event 'go' emits. Only has to fire again when the retryWhen + the 10 intents have **finished**. You also are not setting well the take(10), you need no retry 9 times in order to perform 10 times connection intents.

I have edited my post and added an example. The **mousedown** event simulates your go event. Look at the share() operator, it is important, for more clicks I perform, the source observable gets shared on not fired again the connection.

```js
//emit value every 1s
const source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousedown');
const hotMongoConnect$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000) 
                                 .map(val => {throw val;}) // mocks rxMongo.connect
                                 .retryWhen((errors)=> {
                                     return errors
                                      .scan(function(errorCount, err) {
                                        if(errorCount >= 9) {
                                          throw errorCount + 1;
                                        }
                                        return errorCount + 1;
                                       }, 0)
                                       .do(errorCount => console.log('connect failed. retry nº: ', errorCount))
                                       .delayWhen(val => Rx.Observable.timer(2000));
                                    })
                                    .share();

const example = source.flatMap(() => hotMongoConnect$)
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val), error => console.error('Error connectiong to server, nº of intents:', error));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why I cannot put retryWhen there? I understand that it only has to fire again when there's an error, but there is a case where I need the entire stream to fire like 1 hour after, to do everything again. Can't I do that with events?

Comment: Because you want to retry the connection itself, not the fromEvent source stream. I have one question, the take(10) is to retry the conneciton 10 times? @GuerlandoOCs